# Использование картинок из mysql в формировании таблицы

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Есть таблица, которая полностью формируется из базы данных. Проблема в извлечении картинок из БД. Так ка картинка формируется отдельным php фалом, код которой вытаскивается из blob поля,  как отправить переменную с id строки в файл формирования картинки.

Comment: ООП? Завести отдельный класс, добавить метод создания картинки и использовать его по необходимости? Передавать аргументы  `ImageDraw::createImage($id, $blob);` ? `PHP` всё предоставляет [iMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

Comment: Знаю что это опять будет проигнорировано(не вами а вообще), но **лучший способ** хранить картинки(и другие **файлы**) в БД - это хранить их **в специализированной БД**, например **NTFS\EXT2** (3\4\....) и прочих подобных базах данных... **но** никак **не в реляционных БД**

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я пытаюсь сделать жалкое подобие авито. И мне надо где то хранить картинки объектов.

Comment: Так храните в тех местах которые специально для этого разрабатывались, это файловые системы=) а в вашей БД вы можете успешно хранить путь до файла(например)

Comment: Думал об этом, но гуглив около полутра часа, найти ответ на задачу
(Взять картинку, изменить ей имя на id последнего поля+1.jpg и отправить в общую папку) так и не смог. Вот и выбрал этот, хоть и не правильный путь